# Ejabberd External Auth Error calling HTTPS on Python Script

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

I am implementing external authentication in ejabberd using a python script that call a HTTPS endpoint. But it gives me this error:

```
    [17824] [ERROR] Error authenticating user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ejabberd-18.09/conf/external_auth.py", line 25, in auth_login
    response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 452, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1266, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

The extauth script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import struct
import logging
import os
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

LOGFILE = '/var/log/ejabberd/extauth.log'
ERRFILE = '/var/log/ejabberd/extauth.err'
AUTH_URL= "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed"

def auth_login(token):
    try:
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        payload = {'token': token }

        url = "{}".format(AUTH_URL) 
        logging.info('Url formatted: %s', url)
        request = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(payload), headers)
        response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
        logging.info('Response: %s', response)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as http_err:
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Error authenticating user")
        return False

    return response['valid']

def read():
    (pkt_size,) = struct.unpack('>H', sys.stdin.read(2))
    pkt = sys.stdin.read(pkt_size).split(':')
    cmd = pkt[0]
    args_num = len(pkt) - 1
    if cmd == 'auth' and args_num >= 3:
        logging.debug('User trying to auth')
        is_valid_user = auth_login(pkt[3])

        if is_valid_user:
            logging.debug('Logged User :'+pkt[1]+":"+pkt[2]+":"+pkt[3])
            write(True)
        else:
            logging.info('Error on authenticating user:'+pkt[1]+":"+pkt[2]+":"+pkt[3])
            write(False)
    elif cmd == 'isuser' and args_num == 2:
        logging.debug('isuser received')
        logging.debug(pkt[0]+":"+pkt[1])
        write(False)
    elif cmd == 'setpass' and args_num >= 3:
        logging.debug('setpass received')
        logging.debug(pkt[0]+":"+pkt[1]+":"+pkt[2])
        write(False)
    elif cmd == 'tryregister' and args_num >= 3:
        logging.debug('tryregister received')
        logging.debug(pkt[0]+":"+pkt[1]+":"+pkt[2])
        write(False)
    elif cmd == 'removeuser' and args_num == 2:
        logging.debug('removeuser received')
        logging.debug(pkt[0]+":"+pkt[1])
        write(False)
    elif cmd == 'removeuser3' and args_num >= 3:
        logging.debug('removeuser3 received')
        logging.debug(pkt[0]+":"+pkt[1]+":"+pkt[2])
        write(False)
    else:
        write(False)
    read()
def loop():
    while True:
        try:
            read()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logging.info('Terminating by user input')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception('Input error: ')
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PID = str(os.getpid())
    FMT = '[%(asctime)s] ['+PID+'] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
    sys.stderr = open(ERRFILE, 'a+')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FMT, filename=LOGFILE)
    try:
        loop()
    except struct.error:
        pass
```

In the host config section on ejabberd.yml, the extauth_program property is defined as:

```
extauth_program: "python /opt/ejabberd-18.09/conf/external_auth.py"
```

Actually I am upgrading Ejabberd version from 16.01 to 18.09. In Ejabberd 16.01 this code runs correctly, and when I call this script on a terminal it runs ok too. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: I'm sure you can put lots of logs and see what's wrong. Do you have any issues with it?

Comment: Actually I already printed every line of auth_login method, but what intrigues me is that when calling this script from terminal it runs correctly, and when ejabberd calls it gives error making a Https url(shown on stacktrace above). The last Ejabberd version comes with it's own python and don't use the one installed in the so?